# How to give page break at certain point in pdf while converting html to pdf using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, page-break

I am using jsPDF to convert my html to pdf. My HTML content has few charts. When I convert html to pdf it creates pdf with multiple pages but since I am not able to control the page breaks, my charts renders in two pages.

Please help.

Below is my code.

```
function exportAsPdf(){
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        var options = {
            pagesplit: true
        };
        pdf.addHTML( $("#content") , options, function() {
            //var string = pdf.output('datauristring');
            // $('.preview-pane').attr('src', string);
            pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
        });

    }
```

Ideally, I would like to have one chart in one page only. I display each chart inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<div style="display: block; page-break-after:always"></div>
```

For more configurations check

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Not sure if `jsPDF` supports [CSS 3 Paged Media](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/). If so there are alternative ways to deal with this problem.

Worst case you can create a `white` background `div` with the pre-determined size and re-use it whenever you need page breaks. You can ask in `issues` section in their Github.

Comment: Is it id="page break"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to decrease the chart size while you are writing it in pdf.

Comment: I have 10-15 charts and they come one after another in html. All are small in height. At times it shows 2-3 charts in one page but then the 4th charts gets cut in the pdf.

Comment: then after 3rd chart you can create a new page(pdf.addPage()) or you can use **pdfmake**, because jspdf does not support css.